# Extension of isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

If I have $H_1$ and $H_2$ normal subgroups of $G_1$ and $G_2$ respectively, and both are isomorphic ($H_1$ with $H_2$ and $G_1$ with $G_2$), can we extend the isomorphism between the two $H$ groups to an isomorphism between the two $G$ groups?

Comment: It suffices to consider the case where $G_1 = G_2$, so that what you want is to extend an isomorphism between normal subgroups $H_1$ and $H_2$ to an *automorphism* of $G$ containing both $H_1$ and $H_2$ as normal subgroups.

Comment: In general, this won't be possible. Consider $G_1=G_2 =H_1= \mathbb Z$ and $H_2 = 2\mathbb Z$.

Comment: Also note, that a necessary condition for the existence of an extension of an isomorphism $H_1\cong H_2$ to $G_1\cong G_2$ is, that the quotients $G_1/H_1$ and $G_2/H_2$ be isomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment of User218931 answers your question  for infinite groups.

Here is a counterexample in finite case. This would also be a failure to extend into an automorphism.

Take the symmetric group $S_n\ n\ne6, n>3$; Let $H_1, H_2$ be the subgroups of $S_n$  generated by $(12)$  and $(12)(34)$ respectively. An isomorphism between $H_1, H_2$ cannot be extended to an automorphism of $S_n$.

The reason is the only automorphisms are inner automorphisms in these cases. And an inner automorphism has to preserve the cycle type of a permutation.

Comment: Just a remark: OP wanted the subgroups to be normal.

Comment: @PavelČoupek: OOPS, then my example does not work. Let me think how to make this work with some modifications. Thanks.

Comment: An easy counter-example for finite groups is as follows: Take $G_1 = G_2 = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$, $H_1 = \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z\times \{0\}$ and $H_2 = \{0\}\times 2\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @user218931:  Good example. So the idea is to get  two embedded normal subgroups $H_1,H_2$  such that $G/H_1$ and $G/H_2$ are non-isomorphic. I'll try this  with non-abelian $G$. As $S_n$ is poor with normal subgroups, I've to look elsewhere.

Comment: @PVanchinathan Good luck with finding one! I'd be interested in a non-abelian example.